# Blazor WASM- Bind data coming from Db to dynamically created textboxes

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor-webassembly

I have created textboxes dynamically using RenderFragment in Blazor WASM app. Now I'm performing the edit operation and getting data from Db. I'm able to create the textboxes dynamically in edit mode again but not able to bind the saved values coming from Db to those dynamic textboxes. Please suggest a way to do this.

Comment: @Quango could you please help?

Comment: Can you provide your code if it is convenient for you? If there are errors in the process, share them together.